Ruby process inconsistently hitting 100% CPU Usage
It's somewhat of a shot in the dark, but I'm dealing with a tough problem with a Ruby process that I just can't seem to make any progress on.
I have a non-Rails Ruby process that does a decent amount of processing and memory management, that has run fine in numerous scenarios over the years for long durations (weeks at a time). But with 1 particular data stream I have right now, it runs for 8-12 hours and then suddenly the rate of Major Garbage Collections starts climbing and then it eventually hits 100% CPU usage, and falls behind on processing the incoming data stream.
What's absolutely bizarre, is that restarting the application causes the issue to immediately return, and it hits 100% CPU in 20-30 minutes. This reaches an untenable state of needing constant restarts and falling further behind.
I would think anything related to the Ruby code itself would have a semi-consistent ramp time given the same input data stream, like every 2 hours or something. The input data stream is highly consistent and metered out via hardware, and I've compared log playbacks of that data an nothing changes over the course of the stream. I've done extensive work to try and exonerate both the code, the OS, the overall ENV, etc and cannot find anything.
It's been replicated on multiple different machines (although all have similar builds/configurations/video cards, etc.) but the pattern is very consistent.
CPU temps look good (35-45 C), it's using 0 SWAP memory, and a bunch of stuff like that appears all exonerated.
Has anyone seen anything like this?
